# apache drill: "no current connection" error and "could not find or load main class sqlline.sqlline" error

Tags: apache-drill, sqlline

I am using JDK: 1.8.0.281 and Drill: 1.18.0 on m1 Mac.

I cannot start drill downloaded from https://drill.apache.org/download/ directly. It says
`could not find or load main class sqlline.sqlline`. So I refer to https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline/issues/69, download and compile sqlline and add these two lines

```
BINPATH=/Users/fields/Repositories/sqlline-sqlline-1.9.0/bin
exec java -cp $BINPATH/../target/sqlline-1.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar sqlline.SqlLine "$@"
```

to the beginning of drill/bin/sqlline. Then I start drill-embedded and get `no current connection` every time I enter a query.

Please help me identify the problem. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The distributive from https://drill.apache.org/download/ should be fine for you. Please specify how you start drill-embedded mode?

Comment: Hi @VitaliiDiravka . I finally find out it's my environment variable setting problem. I should not set the DRILL_HOME variable. When I delete it, drill works quite well.

Comment: Yep, it should point to actual drill home from where Drill was running and where /conf and /logs directories are present: https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Yes @cgivre. When I delete DRILL_HOME, Drill works quite well for me.